# Excel VBA - Expand and collapse specific column and row groups on multiple identical sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with multiple sheets, each sheet contains the same table with a number of column sections grouped and a number of row sections grouped (the same columns and rows grouped in each sheet).

I have VBA code to expand all groups on all sheets and the opposite code to collapse all groups on all sheets.

However, I would like to independently expand the same group section on each sheet at the same time (for example columns F:K only on each sheet) without expanding all the other groups.

I would also like the opposite, to be able to collapse a section on each sheet independently from the other expanded groups.

Once I figure out the coding for one section I can then apply it to the other sections. I don't mind having multiple macros, one for each grouping.

Thx

Comment: What have you tried? We are not a free scripting service. My tip is to record a macro, review that code to get an idea of what it is doing, then modify the macro so it's doing what you exactly want.

Comment: @gns100 thanks for the tip, I tried recording a macro originally but it wont recognize selecting the expand/collapse button. I then tried this again using the shortcut Alt + A + J instead but again it did not work. I have code that expands all groups on all sheets and I have been looking for a way to tweak this code for my needs. I tried various code, "Range", "Groups", "ShowDetail" and eventually I have found "Hidden = False" and this looks to have solved my query.

Comment: Sub ExpandFY24Bud()
    Dim b As Worksheet
    For Each b In Worksheets
        b.Columns("BB:BN").Hidden = False
    Next b
End Sub